# Qualification of code - comparisons between signed and unsigned values in libc's qsort

Tags: c, gcc, clang, warnings, signed

While doing a verification pass over code that is safety-critical - and is supposed to be executed in an embedded device - I saw some warnings emitted by both GCC and Clang. The warnings are easy to reproduce, since the code in question comes from the open-source BSD libc:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freebsd/\
freebsd/af3e10e5a78d3af8cef6088748978c6c612757f0/lib/libc/stdlib/qsort.c

$ gcc -c -Wall -Wsign-compare -DI_AM_QSORT_R -Wall qsort.c

qsort.c: In function 'qsort_r':
qsort.c:45:24: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned 
               integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

#define MIN(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? a : b)
                        ^
qsort.c:186:6: note: in expansion of macro 'MIN'
  r = MIN(pd - pc, pn - pd - es);
      ^
qsort.c:45:34: warning: signed and unsigned type in conditional 
               expression [-Wsign-compare]
 #define MIN(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? a : b)
                                  ^
qsort.c:186:6: note: in expansion of macro 'MIN'
  r = MIN(pd - pc, pn - pd - es);
```

To understand these warnings (emitted from both GCC and CLang)...

- `pd`, `pc` and `pn` **are pointers**
- `es` is `size_t` (that is, **`unsigned`**)

It could be argued that C's rules for handling comparisons between signed and unsigned entities can be adequately expressed as [DON'T, FOR THE LOVE OF GOD [1]](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/268).

But in this case, the BSD implementation of `qsort` compares...

- the result of subtracting two pointers (which has a signed type, `ptrdiff_t`)
- to the result of subtracting two pointers, reduced by `es` - which is unsigned.

Why does subtracting an `unsigned` value from a `ptrdiff_t` one (that is, a signed one) result in an `unsigned` one? That's something you can read about in the post referenced above. Suffice to say, that for word-sized entities, any expression of `signed OPERATOR unsigned` results in an `unsigned` type.

So, to cut a long story short, for GCC and CLang to stop complaining, the lines would have to be changed from...

```
r = MIN(pd - pc, pn - pd - es);
```

to either:

```
r = MIN((unsigned)(pd - pc), pn - pd - es)
```

or to:

```
r = MIN(pd - pc, (signed)(pn - pd - es));
```

The question is... what is the right patch?

[1] *"Why Not Mix Signed and Unsigned Values in C/C++?"*, http://blog.regehr.org/archives/268

Comment: If you are *certain* that `es` will always fit the signed type `ptrdiff_t` would it be better to work with that type? Then you won't have to try and fudge the pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thing is, this is not my code - this is the BSD libc code for `qsort`. I am very much afraid this was written back in the 70s (hence the long and overly descriptive variable names). I can therefore only theorize on why they subtract an unsigned from a ptrdiff_t... And if I were to guess, I'd guess this is code that no-one dares touch - for fear of breaking in some combination of platform/compiler :-( Still, I can at least ask the friendly developers of SO to see what they think.

Comment: See what axxle did: http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/qsort.c

Comment: `es` mostly likely stands for "element size".

Comment: @alk: No idea who/what *axxle* is, but clearly he/she went for the first of my two options... (the casts to `size_t` are basically the same as my cast to `unsigned`). Thanks for pointing out that someone else also faced this, but the question remains... why cast on the left and not on the right side of the comparison? Is there a difference - is there a "right one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly I am on my own here :-)

My answer to the question comes from a very simplistic way of looking at things...

If you apply the unsigned cast on the left, and re-compile, the *object file does not change* (verified via MD5 sums). If you instead cast the right side (to signed), the object files DOES change - which means this change deviates (at assembly level, at least - for both amd64 and sparcs) from what the original code was doing.

Short answer: I proceed with casting to unsigned (`size_t`). That's also what [Apple seems to have done](http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/qsort.c) (thanks for the pointer, @alk).